# Java getting number of days between two dates

Tags: java, date, compare, between, days

I am trying to calculate the number of days between two dates.
Even though I found many similar questions, I just cannot come up with a solution.

```
Date lastpickup = (Date) section_userdata.get("lastpickup");
Date today = new Date();
    
Instant instant_lastpickup = lastpickup.toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
Instant instant_today = today.toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

This is my code at the moment.
A date is read from a config and should be compared to the actual date.
With the code I have I am able to determine whether the date is the same or not, but I want to know which amount of days (ideally as an Integer) is between those two.

I want to look at the calendar days, not 24h rhythm.

Comment: Well, the result will depend on the timezone. Which timezone do you want to do the operation in?

Comment: FYI, never use `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`. Both are legacy classes, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `java.time.Instant` and `java.time.LocalDate`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it was way easier than I thought.

Here's my solution

```
long daysCount = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(instant_lastpickup, instant_today);
```

Comment: Your code ignores crucial issue of time zones.